# MySQL 5.x and multiple instances: same mysql database?

Tags: mysql

Looking into running multiple instances of MySQL and wondering if the `mysql` database (which stores the `information_schema` table) is the same for all instances or if they would all have their own.

I'm assuming it's the latter, but wanted to check (means rewriting a backup script if that's the case).

Comment: Same for all instances. Different MySQL instances would run on different ports: 1st - 3306, 2d - 3307 ...e.t.c

Comment: Slap that in an answer and get yourself some mighty fine points, friend. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have separate data files (including the MySQL db) for each instance.
When creating additional instances you need to assign them their own distinct data directory and either copy the data files from the original instance or, preferably, use `mysql_install_db` to initialize the necessary files.

A quick and dirty list of steps [can be found here](http://lasanthals.blogspot.com/2012/09/running-multiple-instances-of-mysql-on.html), though the author doesn't really discuss creating the start/stop scripts in /etc/init.d, [which are discussed here](http://opensourcedbms.com/dbms/running-multiple-mysql-5-6-instances-on-one-server-in-centos-6rhel-6fedora/).

Comment: Nicely done.  Glad I double-checked @Danila Ladner's answer.